# WordPress site redirect permalinks

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a word-press site `example.com` and I am redirecting it to `beta.example.com`.

I want my links to be shown as `example.com/link1` which was previously shown as `beta.example.com/link1`. I am getting the page URL with  `<?php echo get_permalink(id); ?>` I tried to change site address and site URL but its not working. I also tried custom permalinks but its not working.

This is my first WordPress site I may be doing something wrong but I can not figure out what’s going wrong.

Comment: my problem is that when i redirect the site the home page is displaying fine but when i click on the links on the home page, the url again changes to beta.example.com/link. and i need my links to be displayed on base domain linke example.com/link

Comment: I guess you have transfered the page and all the links in the articles are wrong now? 
always transfer a blog via the import/export plugins...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress can also store URLs in the database, in various locations. You can manually edit the database in most cases, but some are stored in serialized objects, which cant be (easily) edited by hand, so you can use a find and replace tool such as http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Be very careful to read the instructions with that tool, take a backup beforehand and remove the script from the server when you are done.

Comment: I can confirm when I moved my wordpress sites, always had to manually edit site URL in DB. Never touched the config files.

Comment: i just changed site URL. and it works. now the problem is a step ahead . i can't customize permalinks. :) i dont need dirty URLS like mysite/?page_id=123

Comment: You should be able to tell WordPress to recreate your .htaccess file, which will solve that. Make sure WordPress has write access to the .htaccess too.

Answer (score 1):

Check your .htaccess file in your root directory for any entries that may be redirecting your links to beta.yoursite.com

Answer (score 0):

WordPress stores that info in:

> example.com/wp-admin/options-general.php

The nice thing about WordPress is even if links in the front-end seem off, the admin area should be working. If not, then something is really amiss. But issues like this are fairly common with WordPress migrations.

That said, I prefer to hard-code the install configuration info in the `wp-config.php` file. You can add the new URL basepath to your `wp-config.php` file like so:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com');
define('WP_HOME',    'http://example.com');
define('WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://example.com/wp-content');
```

I place those near the top of the file just above the database settings. I find that doing it this way makes easier to migrate sites from one URL to another.